# Can I use ASCII to search for symbols in unicode-math formula?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
a $a$
\end{document}
```

It is feasible to use `a` to search for  in the formula in PDF when I use `unicode-math`?

Comment: well theoretically you can by adding an /ActualText, but this would also affect copy&paste. And on the whole I would say that a mathematical  is something different to a and the pdf should reflect this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But if I use non unicode-math mathematical fonts, such as Computer Modern fonts, they are the same.

Comment: Yes I know. But this actually a problem, as in unicode they are different and so they should behave different in search and copy&paste.